# In case of complex numbers what is the value of $i^i$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, exponential-function

Is it possible to get the value of $i^i$?
I want to know what the result of it is.

Comment: Even [Google knows](https://www.google.ch/search?q=what+is+i%5Ei&oq=what+is+i%5Ei&aqs=chrome..69i57j6j69i60.2671j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Answer (score 3):

$$i^i=\left(e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}+2i\pi k}\right)^i,$$
where $k\in\mathbb Z$.

I think it's clear now.

Comment: I would add $=e^{-\frac\pi2+2k\pi i}$.

Comment: @ José Carlos Santos Yes of course!